# Small drop-down list error

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have been creating the navigation menu for my website, I have used drop-down boxes. The first drop-down has worked out nicely however with my second it seems as if the drop-down follows itself, try it here to see for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/yc9byjvh/ also is there any simpler way to make my div's?

```
<div id = "dropdown"><a href = "catalogue.html">PRODUCT CATALOGUE</a>
<ul id="dropdown-list">


<li>
    Vacuum Components
</li>

<li>
    Valve Components
</li>

<li>
    Roughing Components
</li>

<li>
    Vacuum Measurement
</li>

<li>
    Glass Components
</li>

<li>
    Electrical Feedthroughs
</li>

<li>
    Motion and manipulation
</li>

<li>
    Thin Film Products
</li>
</ul>
</div>


<div id = "dropdown2">REQUEST A QUOTE
<ul id ="dropdown-list">

<li>
    Request Print Catalouge
</li>

<li>
    Terms & Conditions
</li>

<li>
    Employment
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
body {font-family: palatino linotype;
background: url(rngbackground.png) repeat 0 0;

}

p{
color:black;
font-family: palatino linotype;
}

h2{
color:grey;
}

h5{
color:grey;
}


a{
color:black;
text-decoration:none;

}

a:hover{
color:blue;

}

a:active{
color:black;
}

a:visited{
color:none;
text-decoration:none
}

#home{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px; 
border:1px solid grey;
width: 18.6%;
text-align:center;
font-family: Palatino Linotype;
font-size: 15px;
-moz-appearance: none;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
text-transform:uppercase;
background:white;
height:2%;
position:absolute; top: 15%; left: 2%;

}

#dropdown:hover ul#dropdown-list{
display:block;
border:1px solid grey;

}
#dropdown ul{
padding:0px;
list-style: none;

}
#dropdown ul li{
width: 100%;
}
#dropdown ul li:hover{
background-color: lightblue;
cursor:pointer;
font-family: Palatino Linotype;
  font-size: 15px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px red inset;
}
#dropdown ul li a{  
padding-left: 10px;
text-decoration:none;
}


/* end 1*/

#dropdown2:hover ul#dropdown-list{
display:block;
border:1px solid grey;

}
#dropdown2 ul{
padding:0px;
list-style: none;

}
#dropdown2 ul li{
width: 100%;
}
#dropdown2 ul li:hover{
background-color: lightblue;
cursor:pointer;
font-family: Palatino Linotype;
  font-size: 15px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px red inset;
}
#dropdown2 ul li a{  
padding-left: 10px;
text-decoration:none;
}

/* end 2*/

#dropdown-list{
width: 100%;

display:none;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
font-family: Palatino Linotype;
  font-size: 15px;
  -moz-appearance: none;

   background-color:white;
 }



#dropdown{

border: 1px solid lightgray;
 padding:5px;
 margin:0px;
 cursor:pointer;
 width:19.25%;
 height:3%;
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;top:24%;left:2.6%;
 font-family: palatino linotype;
 font-size: 15px;
 -moz-appearance: none;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px red inset;
background-color:white;
z-index:+10;
}


#dropdown2 { 
border: 1px solid lightgray;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px; 
width: 18%;
text-align:center;
font-family: Palatino Linotype;
font-size: 15px;
-moz-appearance: none;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px red inset;

position:absolute;top:31%;left:2%;
font-family: palatino linotype;
font-size: 15px;
-moz-appearance: none;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px red inset;
background-color:white;
z-index:+9;
}
```

Comment: can you update you question with a pic of how you want it to look?
and it is possible to use divs but ul -> li are much better.

Comment: I basically want the bottom one to look like the top one.

Comment: hmm in the fiddle you provided they look the same to me (I think lol), the only problem is that they are overlapping eachother.

Comment: for me the bottom drop-down is just an extended box while the top one creates an entirely new box, which is what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
 .dropdown-list{
        width: 100%;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        font-family: Palatino Linotype;
        font-size: 15px;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        background-color:white;
        position: absolute;
        top:31%;
        left:2%;
    }

    .dropdown-list > li { 
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px; 
        width: 18%;
        text-align:center;
        font-family: Palatino Linotype;
        font-size: 15px;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px red inset;
        list-style: none;
        font-family: palatino linotype;
        font-size: 15px;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px red inset;
        background-color:white;
        z-index:9;
     
    }
    
    .dropdown-list > li > ul {
        display: none;
    } 
    .dropdown-list > li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        background: #fff;
        border:1px solid #000;
        list-style: none;
        text-align: left;
    }

.dropdown-list > li > ul >li:hover {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px red inset;
    }
```

```html
<ul class='dropdown-list'>
    <li>
        <a href = "catalogue.html">PRODUCT CATALOGUE</a>
        <ul id="dropdown-list">


            <li>
                Vacuum Components
            </li>

            <li>
                Valve Components
            </li>

            <li>
                Roughing Components
            </li>

            <li>
                Vacuum Measurement
            </li>

            <li>
                Glass Components
            </li>

            <li>
                Electrical Feedthroughs
            </li>

            <li>
                Motion and manipulation
            </li>

            <li>
                Thin Film Products
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> REQUEST A QUOTE 
        <ul id ="dropdown-list">

            <li>
                Request Print Catalouge
            </li>

            <li>
                Terms & Conditions
            </li>

            <li>
                Employment
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO ** http://jsfiddle.net/yc9byjvh/show/

```css
body {font-family: palatino linotype;
background: url(rngbackground.png) repeat 0 0;

}

p{
 color:black;
 font-family: palatino linotype;
}

h2{
 color:grey;
}

h5{
 color:grey;
}


a{
 color:black;
 text-decoration:none;
 
}

a:hover{
 color:blue;
 
}

a:active{
 color:black;
}

a:visited{
 color:none;
 text-decoration:none
}

#home{
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px; 
 border:1px solid grey;
    width: 18.6%;
 text-align:center;
 font-family: Palatino Linotype;
 font-size: 15px;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 background:white;
 height:2%;
 position:absolute; top: 15%; left: 2%;
 
}

#dropdown:hover ul#dropdown-list{
    display:block;
 border:1px solid grey;
 
}
#dropdown ul{
    padding:0px;
    list-style: none;
 
}
#dropdown ul li{
    width: 100%;
}
#dropdown ul li:hover{
    background-color: lightblue;
    cursor:pointer;
 font-family: Palatino Linotype;
   font-size: 15px;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
      box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px red inset;
}
#dropdown ul li a{  
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
}


/* end 1*/

#dropdown2:hover ul#dropdown-list{
    display:block;
 border:1px solid grey;
 
}
#dropdown2 ul{
    padding:0px;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
 
}
#dropdown2 ul li{
    width: 100%;
}
#dropdown2 ul li:hover{
    background-color: lightblue;
    cursor:pointer;
 font-family: Palatino Linotype;
   font-size: 15px;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
      box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px red inset;
}
#dropdown2 ul li a{  
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* end 2*/

#dropdown-list{
    width: 100%;
 
    display:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
 font-family: Palatino Linotype;
   font-size: 15px;
   -moz-appearance: none;

   background-color:white;
}



#dropdown{
   
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    padding:5px;
    margin:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
 width:19.25%;
 height:3%;
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;top:24%;left:2.6%;
 font-family: palatino linotype;
 font-size: 15px;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px red inset;
 background-color:white;
    z-index:+10;
}


#dropdown2 { 
 border: 1px solid lightgray;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px; 
    width: 18%;
 text-align:center;
 font-family: Palatino Linotype;
 font-size: 15px;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px red inset;
 
    position:absolute;top:31%;left:2%;
 font-family: palatino linotype;
 font-size: 15px;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px red inset;
    background-color:white;
 z-index:+9;
    }
```

```html
<div id = "dropdown"><a href = "catalogue.html">PRODUCT CATALOGUE</a>
<ul id="dropdown-list">

  
 <li>
  Vacuum Components
 </li>
  
 <li>
  Valve Components
 </li>
 
 <li>
  Roughing Components
 </li>
 
 <li>
  Vacuum Measurement
 </li>
 
 <li>
  Glass Components
 </li>
 
 <li>
  Electrical Feedthroughs
 </li>
 
 <li>
  Motion and manipulation
 </li>
 
 <li>
  Thin Film Products
 </li>
</ul>
</div>


<div id = "dropdown2">REQUEST A QUOTE
<ul id ="dropdown-list">
 
 <li>
  Request Print Catalouge
 </li>
 
 <li>
  Terms & Conditions
 </li>
 
 <li>
  Employment
 </li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, what did you change?

Comment: I have change  `#dropdown2 ul{ padding:0px; list-style: none;  }` ** TO ** `#dropdown2 ul{ padding:0px; list-style: none; position: absolute;  margin: 0; }`

Comment: Thanks you solved it, do you know of any easier way to do the CSS? for instance now i need to add all the code again for each drop down menu.

Comment: I have added one new ans please check that